# renaming and replacing by string in git repo

Tags: linux, git, replace, zsh, rename

I am working on a project named XXX.
I want to replace **every** instance of XXX to YYY. (I wish to replace the string inside all files and also rename files/directories that contain the string XXX to YYY).

What I have done and where I'm stuck:

```
git checkout -b renameFix

// in zsh

sed -i -- 's/XXX/YYY/g' **/*(D.) // replace

zmv '(**/)(*XXX*)' '$1${2//XXX/YYY}'  // rename files and dirs
```

Now, when I run git status, I get "fatal: unknown index entry format 0x2f700000" error.

Is there a different approach I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your glob (`**/*(D.)`) traverses the `.git` directory.

You can either remove the `D` qualifier, to avoid globbing "hidden" files (files that start with a period) or add another qualifier to filter out files that starts with git.

Something like this might work:

```
ignore_git() { ! [[ $REPLY =~ "^.git" ]] }
printf '%s\n' **/*(D.+ignore_git)
```

I have added the `printf` so that you can verify that you list the files that you want.

You can also take a look at `git ls-files` which can produce a list of files that git tracks.